# Formula to change date every X days(Excel)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I was wondering if there was a formula that would allow excel to automatically change a date every 28 days. I came up with

`=TODAY()+MOD(DATE(2017,1,6)-TODAY(),28)`

But it's not doing quite what I would like it to do. Any suggestions would be incredibly welcome.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use this formula:

```
= TODAY()-MOD(TODAY()+X,28)+Y
```

Where `X` and `Y` are whatever offsets you desire.

Changing `X` controls the "[phase](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phase_(waves))" of when the 28-day jump occurs.

Changing `Y` controls how far away the output date is from the input date.